# I am unable to make a popup appear through js

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup

I'm trying to add a pop up where a heart image will appear after clicking on the album art. I've used this code before to create modals, however, for some reason, it is not working for this one.

```
<div class="main">


    <btn class="btn" id="btn"></btn>
    <div class="like" id="liker">
        <img src="heart.svg" alt="Flowers in Chania">
    </div>
    <div class="info" id="info">
        <div class="albumArt" id="album"></div>
        <div class="song">Song</div>
        <div class="artist">Artist</div>
    </div>`
    <script>
// Get the button that opens the modal
var album = document.getElementById('album');

// Call the buttons into the function

var heart = document.getElementById('liker');


album.onclick = function () {
    heart.style.display = "block";

}

</script>
```

Comment: Your `js` isn't in a `<script/>` tag, is that a typo?

Comment: Oh no it's not a typo, I'm using a separate file for the javascript rather than keeping it all in the html

Comment: I think you should you have a value in album so that it appears in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. See I've added text for the "album" element

```html
<div class="main">

    <btn class="btn" id="btn"></btn>
    <div class="like" id="liker">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/72/heart-icon.png" alt="Flowers in Chania">
    </div>
    <div class="info" id="info">
        <div class="albumArt" id="album">Album</div>
        <div class="song">Song</div>
        <div class="artist">Artist</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // Get the button that opens the modal
      var album = document.getElementById('album');

      // Call the buttons into the function

      let heart = document.getElementById('liker');

      album.onclick = function () {
          heart.style.display = "block";
          setTimeout(() => heart.remove(), 1000);
      }
    </script>
</div>
```